# Why `this` inside if statement in a function that is in an object is needed but not outside? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object, if-statement, this

Code looks like this

```
let car = {
    make: "bmw",
    model: "520",
    isStarted: false,
    start: function() {
        isStarted = true
    },
    drive: function() {
        if (isStarted) {
            console.log("I am driving away....")
        } else {
            console.log("I am still false")
        }
    }
}

car.start();
car.drive();
```

I read that since `isStarted` is part of an object i need to use `this` to tell JavaScript which `isStarted` i am thinking of. But `car.start()` executes like it knows it is `isStarted` from the object without needing `this` keyword, unless

```
....
start: function() {
    if(!isStarted) {
       isStarted = true
    }
}
....
```

`isStarted` is placed inside `if` and now i need `if (this.isStarted)` because it throws undefiend.

Comment: You should use this - alone isStarted may be undefined so it always is false.

Comment: In your `start()` function, `isStarted = true` does not throw an error because it creates a variable that holds the value. However, when you are attemtping to access `isStarted` in the `drive()` method, it will fail since it is not defined.

Comment: isStarted = true, is just creating a global variable. if you console.log(car.isStarted) you will see it still with the false value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to address `this` in the `start` function, otherwise you create a global variable `isStarted`.

```js
let car = {
    make: "bmw",
    model: "520",
    isStarted: false,
    start: function() {
        this.isStarted = true;
    },
    drive: function() {
        if (this.isStarted) {
            console.log("I am driving away....")
        } else {
            console.log("I am still false")
        }
    }
}

car.start();
car.drive();
```

Comment: Thanks, i get why, `drive` executes because it finds the global `isStarted` that is set to `true` and not the one in object